# Capturing of false glide-slope

Tags: air-traffic-control, glideslope

I am curious to know a couple of things regarding glide-slope:

1. How often do ATCs encounter flights capturing false glide-slopes?
2. What is the response expected from ATCs in such a scenario? In other words, is it the duty of ATC to alert the crew of the possibility of a false glide-slope capture.

Comment: It might be quite rare.  Only two results in an [NTSB search](https://www.ntsb.gov/Pages/search.aspx#k=%22false%20glide%20slope%22), and even those aren't really about that.

Comment: Thank you. I have come across this for the first time in the context of PIA 8303. The link is: https://www.airlineratings.com/news/completely-unacceptable-approach-preceded-pk8303-crash/

Comment: On an ils plate there is a table that computes expected altitude at certain distances from a dme ( usually in 1 mile intervals ). Pilots are expected to compare actual altitude with computed one at least 2 times .

Comment: Agreed. But as in the case of above (PIA 8303) it is a possibility, as was noted in an earlier paper. As this involves landing, not always the crew may have time for re-computation. See: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/314141130_A_global_safety_deficiency_False_glide_slope_capture_affecting_aircraft

Comment: I realised that my previous comment is wrong , those are specific actions taken by an airline . 
The incident referred in your link is this : http://avherald.com/h?article=4641efec/0000&opt=0 . 
" The revised policy includes a new horizontal landing gate for ILS interception from above; being the earliest of the following: the FAF, 5 DME, 4 NM for VMC operations and 5 NM for IMC operations."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. in 10 years of working at a small airport serving commercial airliners never.
2. ILS is a pilot interpreted landing aid, ATC has no obligation to follow the plane once established on ILS. ATC has the responsibility to vector the plane to such a position and altitude such that the plane can intercept the localiser and glide slope. At airports doing dependant ILS approaches ( 2 aircraft on 2 parallel runways ) ATC follows the distance between planes, not the altitude/glide slope. If providing radar services the ATC vectors the plane until established on the localiser then it's the crews responsibility to follow the ILS procedure.

Comment: At least in the USA, however, ATC **is** responsible for vectoring aircraft to intercept the glideslope outside of the GS-capture point at an altitude not above the glideslope itself (nor below the published minimum intercept altitude). [JO 7110.65 5–9–1**c**.](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/atc_html/chap5_section_9.html)

Comment: Thank you. Could you please share which country you are referring to?

Comment: I will reword my answer in order to be more clear.

Comment: Thank you @cavver